# jq: Map from nested JSON

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "A": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "value_A"
  },
  "B": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "value_B"
  }
}
```

...and am trying to use JQ to result in the following:

**Desired Output**

```json
{
  "A": "value_A",
  "B": "value_B"
}
```

...where the key takes the direct value of `node.value`.

---

My current attempt:

```
.[] | {value}
```

...returns the following:

```
{
  "value": "value_A"
}
{
  "value": "value_B"
}
```

---

How can I use JQ to produce the desired JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `with_entries`.

```
map_values(.value)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7_AVtUHt1al)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

[`with_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) helps:

```
with_entries(.value |= .value)
```

which is short for `to_entries | map(.value |= .value) | from_entries`

`to_entries` transforms an object of form `{a:b}` into an array in the form `[{key:a, value:b}]`, so in your example:

```
{
  "key": "A",
  "value": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "value_A"
  }
}
```

`.value |= .value` then assigns the content of `.value.value` to `.value`, leaving you with:

```
{
  "key": "A",
  "value": "value_A"
}
```

which is then converted to an object again by `from_entries` (repeated from above: `with_entries(f)` is equivalent to `from_entries|map(f)|from_entries`)

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt

```bash
.[] | {value}
```

just misses the update assignment.

This will work as expected:

```bash
.[] |= .value
```

```json
{
  "A": "value_A",
  "B": "value_B"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A4pWOGpoKjc)

Comment: Which is in fact exactly how [`map_values/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#map(x),map_values(x)) is [defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L33): `def map_values(f): .[] |= f;` :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`map_values()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)):

```
map_values(.value)
```

It runs the filter passed as argument to each value of the input object, collects the results and associates them with the keys of the input object and returns an object.

Check it [online](https://jqplay.org/s/7_AVtUHt1al).